# Как можно отслеживать когда юзер удаляет приложение?

Tags: java, android

Наше приложение работает с `GCM` через который сервер общается с девайсами.

Вопрос вот в чем, допустим такая ситуация, юзер загрузил нашу аппликацию, сервер получил `REG_ID` устройства и отметил его в базе.

Понятно, что в лучшем случае когда у юзера есть доступ к сети и он удаляет приложение об этом можно сообщить серверу, чтоб он обновил информацию о количестве подключенных устройств.

Но как быть если у юзера нет интернета и он удалил приложение...?

Как в таком случае понять актуальное число подключенных юзеров?

Или всю базу нужно поделить на активных и неактивных и раз в какой то период времени(допустим 1 день) проверять на связи юзер или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый правильный способ - через "пинг-понг" - то есть, Ваш сервер отправляет специально сформированный пуш и клиент должен ему ответить (обычно сервер шлет "ping", а клиент отвечает "pong"). Если клиент не отвечает какой то период (например, неделю - это определяется уже менедждерами, которые могут оценить подобное), то клиент переходит в режим "неактивный" и через какое то время удаляется. Как узнать, когда удалить? Очень просто - по истечению жизни токена - сервер гугла отвечает, что токен "истек".

Отслеживание удаления приложения - плохая затея. Допустим, пользователь просто выключил телефон или уронил в бассейн. Приложение недоступно, но пользователь то его не удалял.

В более навороченных системах пользователю предоставляют некую админку, где он может "удалить устройство" или просто можно послать по почте письмо, где написать "Ваше устройство неактивно неделю, мы его скоро удалим или запустите приложение".

Comment: Я примерно так и представлял... Только где то на хабре читал, что это еще называют `heart beating`... Ок, с этим разобрались)) Но подскажите еще пожалуйста что вы имели ввиду здесь `Очень просто - по истечению жизни токена - сервер гугла отвечает, что токен "истек".` Где можно про это почитать? Не совсем понял я сервер гугла куда отвечает? и какой срок действия этого токена? И токен это вы имеете ввиду этот ID который я получаю от GCM?

Comment: **сервера гугла** - GMC,
**сервер гугла отвечает** - отвечает в на попытку оптавить пуш (возможно, Вы просто не проверяете ответ).
**какой срок действия этого токена** -  я видел и день, и несколько дней. Я подоздреваю, что гугл может легко их "сделать невалидными", так как обнаружил попытку несанкционированного использования.

Comment: Ок, значит я должен сделать  "пинг-понг" и если неделю нет ответа, то переношу пользователя в неактивные, потом проверяю  токен и если его срок действия истек то удаляю пользователя, верно? А как часто гугл обновляет токены и какой срок его действия по умолчанию?

Comment: я давно работал  с этим (несколько лет назад) и видел различное время. Дефолтного времени **не знаю**. Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590482/do-gcm-registration-ids-expire) пишут, что он похоже уже и не экспайриться. Кому верить - не знаю.

Comment: Но в целом можно взять условно неделю если юзер не отвечает, то отправлять в неактивные, если прошел месяц то удалять его... Как вы считаете такая тактика норм?

Comment: я бы делал это дело в конфиг. А дальше по обстоятельствам.